# Any way to find if two adjacent new lines start with certain words?

Tags: perl, bash, sed, grep

Say I have a file like so:

```
+jaklfjdskalfjkdsaj
fkldsjafkljdkaljfsd
-jslakflkdsalfkdls;
+sdjafkdjsakfjdskal
```

I only want to find and count the amount of times during this file a line that starts with `-` is immediately followed by a line that starts with `+`.

Rules:

- No external scripts
- Must be done from within a bash script
- Must be inline

I could figure out how to do this in a Python script, for instance, but I've never had to do something this extensive in Bash.

Could anyone help me out? I figure it'll end up being `grep`, `perl`, or maybe a talented `sed` line -- but these are things I'm still learning.

Thank you all!

Comment: Removed the Python tag as you don't appear to want an answer using it.

Comment: Thanks! I was told I could use `python`, so long as it was inline, so I figured I'd include it anyway. Thanks for correcting the mistake!

Comment: Python's not great for one liners on the command line... so wouldn't be a viable answer

Comment: Though not great for one liners, it is *possible*, and is capable of working, and therefore is a viable answer. Thanks for the edit though! `perl`, `awk`, or `grep` were all much more suited for the job, so you're right in a way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy in Perl:

```
perl -lne '$c++ if $p and /^\+/; $p = /^-/ }{ print $c' FILE
```

Comment: This is perfect! Do you mind if I ask how you got started on learning Perl regexes? I can't seem to get started to wrap my mind around it.

Comment: `}{` should be similar to `END{}`. Is there any reference for this syntax?

Comment: @mpapec: It is called the "Eskimo greeting operator". See http://www.catonmat.net/blog/secret-perl-operators/#eskimo

Comment: @JamesRoseman : [`perldoc perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html), [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html), and (if you're feeling brave) [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), in that order.

Answer (score 10):

`grep -A1 "^-" $file | grep "^+" | wc -l`

The first grep finds all of the lines starting with `-`, and the `-A1` causes it to also output the line after the match too.

We then grep that output for any lines starting with `+`. Logically:

1. We know the output of the first grep is only the `-XXX` lines and the following lines
2. We know that a `+xxx` line cannot also be a `-xxx` line

Therefore, any `+xxx` lines must be following lines, and should be counted, which we do with `wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

**awk** one-liner:

```
awk -v FS='' '{x=x sprintf("%s", $1)}END{print gsub(/-\+/,"",x)}' file
```

e.g.

```
kent$  cat file
+jaklfjdskalfjkdsaj
fkldsjafkljdkaljfsd
-jslakflkdsalfkdls;
+sdjafkdjsakfjdskal
-
-
-
+
-
+
foo
+

kent$  awk -v FS='' '{x=x sprintf("%s", $1)}END{print gsub(/-\+/,"",x)}' file
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Perl example.  Not as terse as choroba's, but more transparent in how it works:

```
perl -e'while (<>) { $last = $cur; $cur = $_; print $last, $cur if substr($last, 0, 1) eq "-" && substr($cur, 0, 1) eq "+" }' < infile
```

Output:

```
-jslakflkdsalfkdls;
+sdjafkdjsakfjdskal
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure bash:

```
unset c p
while read line ; do
    [[ $line == +* && $p == 0 ]] && (( c++ ))
    [[ $line == -* ]]
    p=$?
done < FILE
echo $c
```